# Replace column based on string

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to replace column "Names" by a new variable "Gender" based on the first letters that we find in column name.

INPUT:

```
df['Name'].value_counts()
```

OUTPUT:

```
Mr. Gordon Hemmings     1
Miss Jane Wilkins       1
Mrs. Audrey North       1
Mrs. Wanda Sharp        1
Mr. Victor Hemmings     1
                       ..
Miss Heather Abraham    1
Mrs. Kylie Hart         1
Mr. Ian Langdon         1
Mr. Gordon Watson       1
Miss Irene Vance        1

Name: Name, Length: 4999, dtype: int64
```

Now, see the Miss, Mrs., and Miss? The first question that comes to mind is: how many different words there are?

INPUT

```
df.Name.str.split().str[0].value_counts(dropna=False)

Mr.     3351
Mrs.     937
Miss     711
NaN        1

Name: Name, dtype: int64
```

Now I'm trying to:

```
    #Replace missing value

df['Name'].fillna('Mr.', inplace=True)

# Create Column Gender
df['Gender'] = df['Name']

for i in range(0, df[0]):  


    A = df['Name'].values[i][0:3]=="Mr." 
    df['Gender'].values[i] = A

df.loc[df['Gender']==True, 'Gender']="Male"
df.loc[df['Gender']==False, 'Gender']="Female"

del df['Name'] #Delete column 'Name'

df
```

But I'm missing something since I get the following error:

> KeyError: 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `KeyError` is because you don't have a column called `0`. However, I would ditch that code and try something more efficient.

You can use `np.where` with `str.contains` to search for names with `Mr.` after using `fillna()`. Then, just `drop` the `Name` column.:

```
df['Name'] = df['Name'].fillna('Mr.')
df['Gender'] = np.where(df['Name'].str.contains('Mr\.'), 'Male', 'Female')
df = df.drop('Name', axis=1)
df
```

Full example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Name': {0: 'Mr. Gordon Hemmings',
  1: 'Miss Jane Wilkins',
  2: 'Mrs. Audrey North',
  3: 'Mrs. Wanda Sharp',
  4: 'Mr. Victor Hemmings'},
 'Value': {0: 1, 1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 1, 4: 1}})
print(df)
df['Name'] = df['Name'].fillna('Mr.')
df['Gender'] = np.where(df['Name'].str.contains('Mr\.'), 'Male', 'Female')
df = df.drop('Name', axis=1)
print('\n')
print(df)
                  Name  Value
0  Mr. Gordon Hemmings      1
1    Miss Jane Wilkins      1
2    Mrs. Audrey North      1
3     Mrs. Wanda Sharp      1
4  Mr. Victor Hemmings      1


   Value  Gender
0      1    Male
1      1  Female
2      1  Female
3      1  Female
4      1    Male
```

Comment: That didn't work... I get this:

df['Gender'].value_counts()

Male    4289

Female    711

Name: Gender, dtype: int64

But that is wrong... It seems he just diferentiated Miss, when he should return true only to "Mr." and False otherwise.

Comment: @jps17183  I forgot that `.` is a regex charachter, so you need to escape it with `/`.